# identifier unexpected in my react project

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, sass

am new to react and i was following a tutorial while learning and i had an error that i don't even understand. the error is from "=>" in my code.

````
  const { isLoginActive } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className = "App">
      <div className = "login">
        <div className = "container">
          {isLoginActive && <Login containerRef = {(ref)} **=>** this.current = ref} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}```
````

Comment: Voting to lose because the problem is caused by a typo. You have a misplaced `}` in there. The syntax is `attribute={expression}` not `attribute={exp}ression}`

Comment: So what @Quentin is saying, it's `containerRef = {(ref) => this.current = ref}` without the extra `}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra `}` from the line like

```
{isLoginActive && <Login containerRef={ (ref) => this.current = ref} />}
```